# SQL query to check multiple values of multiple columns

Tags: sql

I have a *homework assignment* that I can't seem to figure out.

I don't want the entire query as an answer, that's why I won't include any table structures or SQL. I just need some information on how to tackle this issue in SQL. Any help will be appreciated!

Given the following result table, how can I check (per row) if the Location_ID value of ID is the same as the Location value of ID's Substitute?
The query should give me a new table for every case where the locations don't match.

[Example result table](http://oi60.tinypic.com/10sdmyu.jpg)

E.G. ID 1 has a location of 45 and 5 as Substitute. ID 5 has a location of 67, so they should be listed in the result table of the query.

ID 3 has a location of 34 and 2 as a substitute. ID 2 also has a location of 34, so ID 3 should be left out of the result table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the Idea is to use a self join, something like:

```
select * from Mytable as a join Mytable as b on a.ID=b.ID
where a.Substitute!=b.Location_ID
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I needed the self join in this case! 
I had to change the query a bit though, to check against both the ID's locations.

```
    select * from Mytable as a join Mytable as b on a.ID=b.ID 
    where a.Location_ID!=b.Location_ID
```

Much appreciated!